# How to count rows from multiple tables MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, count, rows

How can I count all the rows from 2 tables where...

```
`approved` == '0'
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do an aggregate on a union:

```
select sum(subcount) as totalcount 
    from ( select count(*) as subcount from table1 where approved = 0
           union
           select count(*) as subcount from table2 where approved = 0 )
```

There are other ways but this shows your intent very clearly, especially naming the columns this way.

Hope this helps

Comment: Will return incorrect value if the two sub-counts are identical. `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` should fix the problem.

Comment: Throws the following error: Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score -1):

You would do this for each table:

`SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE approved = 0`

You could combine it into one query but that gets more complicated. Either use a subquery or union.

Answer (score -1):

This answer will help you:

```
$query = "select count(*)+(select count(*) from table1) as totalrows from table2";
```