# Using COUNT across multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, count

I have the following code which counts the number of records in my JB_Employer table, but I also want to add the total number of records from a second (and possibly third) table to this.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS 'Number of employees'
FROM JB_Employer
WHERE Employer_ID >0
```

Also if anyone can advise me how to put this in to PHP I would appreciate it, having a little trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Voting to close. Not only does the question consist of two questions, but also the first question is unclear, because neither the database nor the relation between the tables is specified and the second question shows no research at all; there must be a million examples of connecting to a database in PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count rows from multiple tables MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487348/how-to-count-rows-from-multiple-tables-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (
SELECT count(*) from table1
) as `table1_count`, (
SELECT count(*) from table2
) as `table2_count`
```

if you want to add them up

```
SELECT (
SELECT count(*) from table1
) + (
SELECT count(*) from table2
) as `total_count`
```